# Numerov method for 1D potential barrier problem: numerical errors

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics

I wanted to solve a 1D potential barrier problem. It seemed easy enough to do: set a travelling wave coming from the left, part of it gets reflected by the barrier, and part of it gets gets transmitted on the right:
$$\Psi(z) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
e^{ikz} + r e^{-ikz} & \mathrm{if} & z<=0 \\
te^{ikz} & \mathrm{if} & z>=L
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Then I create an array containing the potential $V(z)$, an array for the wave function, and I start with the boundary condition $\Psi(N\Delta z)$, $\Psi((N-1)\Delta z)$, where $(N-3)\Delta z =L$ and $N$ is the number of grid points.

Then I use [Numerov's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerov%27s_method) to get from $N$ to $0$ and find the wave function.

To check, I calculate $e^{ikz}$, and I compare to the solution for $\Psi$ if $V(z)=0$ and the energy of the particle is $k^2/2m$. They should be identical, but they are slightly different. It seems that the finer grid doesn't help much.

Is there an issue I'm missing? I also tried to make the grid a lot finer than the period of the oscillation along $z$.

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic If it gets the question answered, why not. Can you move it there?